# MySQL SELECT count with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `rank` WHERE entry_id = '90901' ORDER BY position ASC
229298400   90901   33
232322400   90901   33
227487600   90901   37
229903200   90901   38
228092400   90901   41
228693600   90901   43
225673200   90901   45
230508000   90901   47

SELECT position FROM `rank` WHERE entry_id = '90901' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1 
33

SELECT position, count(*) as Weeks FROM `rank` WHERE entry_id = '90901' ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1 
45  8
```

Please explain why '45' (second last?) is returned and how to count all entries and get the highest one.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: 'Without GROUP BY, there is a single group and it is nondeterministic which'  position  'value to choose for the group' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: But with GROUP BY I can't get a total count(*). So there is no way to do this in a one query? (SELECT position, count(*) as Weeks FROM `rank` WHERE entry_id = '90901' GROUP BY position ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1)

Comment: Is there anyway you could edit your Question with the table definition for at least the 3 columns you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to query on entry_id then max(position)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE t(id int,entry_id int,position int);
insert into t values
(229298400 ,  90901  , 33),
(232322400 ,  90901  , 33),
(227487600 ,  90901  , 37),
(229903200 ,  90901  , 38),
(228092400 ,  90901  , 41),
(228693600 ,  90901  , 43),
(225673200 ,  90901  , 45),
(230508000 ,  90901  , 47);

select max(position) , count(*)
from t
where entry_id = 90901;

+---------------+----------+
| max(position) | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
|            47 |        8 |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

if you want the same for every entry_id then

```
select entry_id, max(position) , count(*)
from t
group by entry_id

+----------+---------------+----------+
| entry_id | max(position) | count(*) |
+----------+---------------+----------+
|    90901 |            47 |        8 |
+----------+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! SELECT MIN(position), count(*) as Weeks FROM `rank` WHERE entry_id = '90901'